# Образование прилагательных от существительных иноязычного происхождения

Tags: словообразование

Возможно ли образование прилагательных от существительных иноязычного происхождения (несклоняемых)? Речь о словах типа кенгуру, пальто, Рено, торнадо и так далее.

Comment: В принципе возможно многое, но есть ли необходимость? Можете привести пример того что бы Вам бы хотелось образовать? Торнадистая погода? Пальтовый бутик? А от "рено".... реновый?

Comment: Да, что-то вроде этого. Просто не хотелось, не имея познаний в этой области, предлагать варианты. Мой приятель как-то выразился: "Кенгурушная сумка", вот я и обратил внимание на это слово, на его замешательство при его образовании.

Answer (score 1):

В разговоре всякое может пригодиться, но скорее всего, однократно (*реношные* запчасти, *торнадский* сотона, *пальтовый* бутик, *кенгуровое* филе или манто). Прилагательное **кенгуровый** используется в названиях подвидов грызунов.

> Купил реношные колеса:
>
> Мой джип как зверь - торнадист стал.
>
> Ты, пешеход пальтовый, - с носом,
>
> Эк кенгуровый хвост поджал!

Answer (score 0):

С кенгуру проблем нет. "Кенгуриный" есть в любом словаре. "Кенгуровый" - это уже профессиональное экзотика. Как и все остальное: пальтовое сукно, торнадовая опасность, реношные диски, деповский рабочий...

Нормативность последних варьируется от литературной нормы (пальтовый) до абсолютно невозможной ("метровый" - от "метро", "брашный" - от "бра" и т.д.).

Comment: Проверять в каждом индивидуальном случае?

Comment: Есть кенгуровая мышь, да. А если кенгуриная - то разве что блоха ))

Comment: @ddbug Ну нехай блоха... В смысле - мтдящая на кенгуру, но не в смысле видовой принадлежности. "Кенгуровый" - термин чисто биологический, там традиционно все с уклоном в мужской род. А кенгуриный - все остальное - от кенгурятника да сумки.

Comment: @Владимир Хороший вопрос, но короткого ответа у меня нет. Если произносите ответственную речь, или пишете в газету, слова лучше проверять. В разговорной речи - чувствуйте себя свободно. Можете попробовать и изобрести новое слово. Ничего страшного не будет. Дети делают это каждый день.